# ViewPager2 does not refresh the Fragment View while using FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I am using viewPager2 and this is my dependency `implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"`

But I wont able to update my fragment view while using  `notifyDataSetChanged()`

I wanted to update a button view of my fragment.
I tried to update manually  but wont be success.

```
if (item is CategoryProduct) {
                if (this::addBtn.isInitialized) {
                    addBtn.setProductQuantity(item.quantity.toLong())
                }
            }
```

But when I swipe the viewPager I am getting isInitialized false for that particular view , If I have not scrolled its working properly please help me in this.

Please help me if any one can.